# Flux without React .. is reliable option?

Tags: reactjs, flux

What I understood from Flux documentation that it recommend re-rendering view for any minor change raised by store. But what if I am using Flux without React that compliments re-rendering complete view by virtual DOM and rendering just diff.

What if I wanted to implement only Flux without React , won’t re-rendering complete view for every dam change in store be performance bottleneck  .. ?

Answer (score 2):

Flux does not recommend re-rendering view for minor changed raised by Store, but instead, empowers you to control when your DOM re-renders.

> From the Flux Documentation,
>   [image: From the flux docs]

1. The store updates themselves in response to action, but this does not affect the View.
2. The View updates only when the store **emits a change event**, which means, Flux gives you total control as to when you wish to update your View.

Also, all the Views do not get updated, only those (*controller-views*) which listen to specific variable changes inside the Store get updated. This makes your application more performant.

If you wish to follow the same architecture outside React, you can always do that, but it does not mean you will have to update the complete View on all changes inside your store, which implies, it should not become a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is correct: re-rendering the whole view for any state change will destroy your app's performance.

Re-rendering the view works well with React and Flux together because of React's ability to selectively update the DOM. When you change a prop on a component, React rebuilds the entire DOM in memory as a "virtual DOM", without pushing the changes to the actual DOM. Then it applies only the differences between this virtual DOM and the real DOM, making it a very efficient process.

If you want to use Flux without React, you'll need to manage the update process yourself. So, for example, if your state has 50 different values and you change one, you will need to identify the elements associated with that one value and update it accordingly, leaving the others untouched.